# jquery: event.stopImmediatePropagation() vs return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is there any difference between calling `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `return false` inside an event handler ?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Yes they are different.

`return false` is basically the same as calling both, [**`event.stopPropagation()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and [**`event.preventDefault()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Whereas [**`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) is the same as `event.stopPropagation()` *plus* preventing other registered event handlers on the same element to be executed. So it does not prevent the default action for an event, such as following a clicked link.

In short:

```
                            stop   |    prevent     | prevent "same element"
                          bubbling | default action | event handlers

return false                 Yes           Yes             No
preventDefault               No            Yes             No
stopPropagation              Yes           No              No
stopImmediatePropagation     Yes           No              Yes
```

<del>`return false` also works in "normal" JavaScript event handlers</del>

`event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` also work in "normal" JavaScript event handlers (in a W3C compatible browser),  whereas `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` is an extension from jQuery (**update:** apparently it is part of the [DOM Level 3 Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#widl-Event-stopImmediatePropagation)).

**Note:** `return false` **does not** prevent the event from bubbling up in **"normal"** (non-jQuery) event handlers (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false/1357151#1357151))(but still prevents the default action).

---

Maybe worth reading:

- [*jQuery Events: Stop (Mis)Using Return False*](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)
- [*quirksmode.org - Event order*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Comment: The `stopImmediatePropagation` link is broken. The new one is http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#widl-Event-stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for great explanation and table.  Also event.stopImmediatePropagation() will only stop "same type of events" attached to a element. For example, if there are 3 click handler and one mousedown event handler attached to same element. One of the click handler has evt.stopImmediatePropagation() then it won't fire other click handlers.

[**example jsbin**](https://jsbin.com/yileyey/edit?html,js,console,output)

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Answer (score 4):

Returning `false` will stop event bubbling, but other bound events will fire.  However `stopImmediatePropagation` prevents other bound events from firing and stops bubbling.

**Code Example of this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/PcUfP/).**

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete demo for `return false`, `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation` and `stopImmediatePropagation`:

```js
var kid = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var dad = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

kid.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('kid here');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

kid.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('neighbour kid here');
});

dad.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   console.log('dad here');
});

dad.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   console.log('neighbour dad here');
});
```

```html
<div>
    <button>press</button>
</div>
```

(Also available on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jquh3go/).)

The table in [manwal’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27812995) is not fully correct.

```
                            stop   |    prevent     |       prevent
                          bubbling | default action |    event handlers
                                   |                |  Same Element  |  Parent Element

return false                 Yes           Yes               No           No
preventDefault               No            Yes               No           No
stopPropagation              Yes           No                No           Yes
stopImmediatePropagation     Yes           No                Yes          **Yes**
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. event.stopImmediatePropagation() won't let any other handlers for that event be called, regardless of where they are bound. Return false only stops handlers bound to other elements (ie not the same element as the event handler dealing with the stopImmediatePropagation() call) from receiving the event.

Answer (score 0):

@FelixKling answer's table having great concept:

I am posting more explained table:

```
                            stop   |    prevent     |       prevent          |
                          bubbling | default action |    event handlers      |
                                                     Same Element  |  Parent Element

return false                 Yes           Yes             No           No
preventDefault               No            Yes             No           No
stopPropagation              Yes           No              No           Yes
stopImmediatePropagation     Yes           No              Yes          No
```

> Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5302939/2236219