# Stop added event listener functions after one returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function to bind onblur events to elements. The function takes three string variables. The id of the element, the function you want to bind to the element, and any parameters it may need. Then within the function I use [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) to utilize a string to call a function.

Each function that is bound on blur is a validation function that will return true or false. My goal is to make it so that if multiple onblur events are added to the element, and any one of them returns false, the next ones will not be called. But as it's written right now each event that is added to the element fires even if there is a return false.

Both my jquery and javascript version below add multiple onblur events, and fire them all whether they return true or false.

```
this.bindFormElements = function(elementId, ruleName, ruleParameters)
{
    var onBlurEvent = function() 
    {
        if(dynFormSkin[ruleName](this, ruleParameters) == false)
        { 
            return false;   
        }
    };

    document.getElementById(elementId).addEventListener("blur", onBlurEvent, false);
}
```

...

```
this.bindFormElements = function(elementId, ruleName, ruleParameters)
{
    $("#" + elementId).blur(function() 
    {
        if(dynFormSkin[ruleName](this, ruleParameters) == false)
        {
            return false;   
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for: `event.stopImmediatePropagation`  Docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: Perfect! Add it as an answer so I can accept. Did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `return false` is the same as doing:

```
event.stopPropagation()
event.preventDefault()
```

`stopPropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree to parent elements and `preventDefault()` just prevents any "default" action, like following a link.

What you're looking for is called `stopImmediatePropagation()`.  This will stop any other event handlers on the same element (as well as its parents).

```
this.bindFormElements = function(elementId, ruleName, ruleParameters)
{
    $("#" + elementId).blur(function(event) 
    {
        if(dynFormSkin[ruleName](this, ruleParameters) == false)
        {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;   
        }
    });
};
```

For more info, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5302939